# Unable to insert a new item at a specific index into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to insert a new item at a specific index into an array.

I have this code:

```js
const insertAt = (index: number, ...element: QC[]) => {
  const arrCopy = [...qt]
  return arrCopy.splice(index, 0, ...element)
}

const newQC: QC[] = [
  {
    id: cuid(),
    order: qt.length + 1,
  }
]

questionIndex !== undefined &&
  setQt(qt => {
    return insertAt(questionIndex, ...newQC)
  })
```

What this is doing is that it deletes everything from the array returned by `setQt`.

`setQt` is a `useState` function so it has to return a new state.

What could possibly be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splice returns the deleted items (in your case you have 0 deleted items as a second argument) so it returns an empty array. I think, you need something like that

```
const insertAt = (index: number, ...element: QC[]) => {
    const arrCopy = [...qt];
    arrCopy.splice(index, 0, ...element);
    return arrCopy;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use spread syntax for inserting:

```
return [...qt.slice(0, index), ...element, ...qt.slice(index)];
```

Answer (score 1):

that happens because the javascript "splice" function modifies the array, but returns an array with the elements removed. In your case, an empty array.

You can check it in the following link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice